# Using parameters with dynamic data in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Hi I have the following SQL with which I can get data. So I am trying to use a parameter to show only the data based on a week. When I run the query the define query parament dialog opens but when I click ok after that I get an error saying:
An error occurred while executing the query.
Incorrect syntax near ';'. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)

If I don't declare the parameter then it gives me an error that says I have to declare the paramenter. If I choose the datatype of the parameter then the query run but define parameter dialog doesn't appear.

I am not sure what I doing here wrong. I have looked at everything that is available but i can't seem to figure it out.

```
Declare @Week;

WITH Day_Level
AS
(
    SELECT Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork, 
    Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate,
    Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork,
    x.[[WorkingItem]].[System_Id]]],
    [Date].[Date] AS '[Date].[Date]',
    [Date].[WeekOfYear] AS '[Date].[WeekOfYear]',
    [Date].[WeekString] AS '[Date].[WeekString]',
    CONCAT(LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Date].[Date]),3),'.') AS '[Date].[Weekday]',
    [Date].[Year] AS '[Date].[Year]',
    [Date].[YearString] AS '[Date].[YearString]'
    FROM
    (
        select 
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork,
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate,
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork,
        [Item].[System_Id] AS '[WorkingItem].[System_Id]',
        [Date].[Date] AS '[Date].[Date]',
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item].[System_Id], [Date].[Date] ORDER BY [Date].[Date], [Item].[System_Rev] DESC, [Fact].[LastUpdatedDateTime] DESC) AS RN
        from dbo.FactWorkItemHistory Fact
        inner join dbo.DimWorkItem Item
        on fact.WorkItemSK = item.WorkItemSK
        and fact.TeamProjectSK = item.TeamProjectSK
        inner join dbo.DimDate [date]
        on fact.DateSK = [date].DateSK
        inner join dbo.DimTeamProject Project
        on project.ProjectNodeSK = fact.TeamProjectSK
        inner join dbo.DimPerson Person
        on person.PersonSK = item.System_AssignedTo__PersonSK
        inner join DimIteration Iteration
        on iteration.IterationSK = item.IterationSK
        where fact.RevisionCount is not null AND 
        [Project].[ProjectPath] = '\B2B_CRM\PhProduct'
    ) AS x
    inner join dbo.DimDate [date]
    on x.[[Date]].[Date]]] = [date].[Date]
    WHERE x.RN = 1
    AND Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork IS NOT NULL
),
Attributes
AS
(
    select 


    [Fact].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork] AS '[WorkItemFact].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork]',

    [Fact].[Sca_Common_CompletedWorkTotal] AS '[WorkItemFact].[Sca_Common_CompletedWorkTotal]',


    [Item].[Sca_Common_WBS] AS '[WorkItem].[Sca_Common_WBS]',
    LEFT([Item].[Sca_Common_WBS], 18) AS '[WorkItem].[Sca_Common_WBS_Short]',
    [Item].[Sca_Common_WBSType] AS '[WorkItem].[Sca_Common_WBSType]',
    [Item].[System_Id] AS '[WorkItem].[System_Id]',

    [Person].[Name] AS '[AssignedTo].[Name]',
    IIF (YEAR([Item].[System_RevisedDate]) = 9999, 'True', 'False') AS '[WorkItem].[LastRevision]',
    [Iteration].[IterationPath] AS '[WorkItem].[Iteration]'
    from dbo.FactWorkItemHistory Fact
    inner join dbo.DimWorkItem Item
    on fact.WorkItemSK = item.WorkItemSK
    and fact.TeamProjectSK = item.TeamProjectSK
    inner join dbo.DimTeamProject Project
    on project.ProjectNodeSK = fact.TeamProjectSK
    inner join dbo.DimPerson Person
    on person.PersonSK = item.System_AssignedTo__PersonSK
    inner join DimIteration Iteration
    on iteration.IterationSK = item.IterationSK
    where fact.RevisionCount is not null AND 
    [Project].[ProjectPath] = '\B2B_CRM\PhProduct'
    and YEAR([Item].[System_RevisedDate]) = 9999
),

Final
AS
(
SELECT 
ISNULL(Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork - lag(Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork) over (PARTITION BY Day_Level.[[WorkingItem]].[System_Id]]] order by Day_Level.[[Date]].[Date]]]),Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork)
AS CompletedWork,
Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate AS OriginalWork,
Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork AS RemainingWork,
Day_Level.[[Date]].[WeekOfYear]]] AS WeekNumber,
*
FROM Day_Level
INNER JOIN Attributes
ON Day_Level.[[WorkingItem]].[System_Id]]] = Attributes.[[WorkItem]].[System_Id]]]
)

Select *
FROM Final
where WeekNumber = (@Week)
```

Comment: Do a binary search to find the problem, i.e. remove half of the query, did the error disappear or not.

Comment: The query works fine if I remove the transact SQL where clause at the end and the declaration at the top.

Comment: Is there more than one week number returned? What happens with you use `Select * FROM Final where WeekNumber = (@Week)`

Comment: @JonTout If I remove the where statement the query works fine with returning all the data which has several weeks of the yeah (41,42,42,43 e.t.c).It gives me an error that I have ';' near the declaration of the variable '@Week'. If I define the datatype of the variable '@Week' then it returns nothing because the the value of '@Week' is set to null.

Comment: @OmerFarooqKhan You have to declare a value (or values) to the parameter, example (in SQL) something like `Declare @Week INT = 41` which would return just week 41 from that query.
In SSRS you would have to add those values to the parameter.

Comment: @JonTout I have done that and it works. But what I want is that I get the define query paramers dialog box to open and then allow me use that to select the parameter values and also be added to the parameters in SSRS.

Comment: @JonTout btw I am using this tutorial to add the parameters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Using your CTE, in SSRS create a dataset along the lines of

```
Select distinct WeekNumber
FROM Final
```

Assign that dataset to your **(@Week)** parameters (which should appear in Report Builder (or whatever else you're using to build the report)[image]

Default Values can be set by using the same dataset and you might want to allow multiple values as well.

In this instance, my dataset is called dsOfferingType but the data is taken from the results dataset...

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

@JonTout I get what you are saying but this not what I want. So I minimized the query to the following where you can see that I have a put in a parameter (variable) at the end and when I query using this it opens up a [dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwgM3.png) like this.

```
select 
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork,
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate,
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork,
        [Item].[System_Id] AS '[WorkingItem].[System_Id]',
        [Date].[Date] AS '[Date].[Date]',
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item].[System_Id], [Date].[Date] ORDER BY [Date].[Date], [Item].[System_Rev] DESC, [Fact].[LastUpdatedDateTime] DESC) AS RN
        from dbo.FactWorkItemHistory Fact
        inner join dbo.DimWorkItem Item
        on fact.WorkItemSK = item.WorkItemSK
        and fact.TeamProjectSK = item.TeamProjectSK
        inner join dbo.DimDate [date]
        on fact.DateSK = [date].DateSK
        inner join dbo.DimTeamProject Project
        on project.ProjectNodeSK = fact.TeamProjectSK
        inner join dbo.DimPerson Person
        on person.PersonSK = item.System_AssignedTo__PersonSK
        inner join DimIteration Iteration
        on iteration.IterationSK = item.IterationSK
        where fact.RevisionCount is not null AND 
        [Project].[ProjectPath] = '\B2B_CRM\PhProduct'
        AND Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork IS NOT NULL
        AND Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork = @Something
```

Now that I add the second part like this then it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz9o6.png). Don't know what is causing it to be like this.

```
SELECT Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork, 
    Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate,
    Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork,
    x.[[WorkingItem]].[System_Id]]],
    [Date].[Date] AS '[Date].[Date]',
    [Date].[WeekOfYear] AS '[Date].[WeekOfYear]',
    [Date].[WeekString] AS '[Date].[WeekString]',
    CONCAT(LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Date].[Date]),3),'.') AS '[Date].[Weekday]',
    [Date].[Year] AS '[Date].[Year]',
    [Date].[YearString] AS '[Date].[YearString]'
    FROM
    (
        select 
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork,
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate,
        Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork,
        [Item].[System_Id] AS '[WorkingItem].[System_Id]',
        [Date].[Date] AS '[Date].[Date]',
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Item].[System_Id], [Date].[Date] ORDER BY [Date].[Date], [Item].[System_Rev] DESC, [Fact].[LastUpdatedDateTime] DESC) AS RN
        from dbo.FactWorkItemHistory Fact
        inner join dbo.DimWorkItem Item
        on fact.WorkItemSK = item.WorkItemSK
        and fact.TeamProjectSK = item.TeamProjectSK
        inner join dbo.DimDate [date]
        on fact.DateSK = [date].DateSK
        inner join dbo.DimTeamProject Project
        on project.ProjectNodeSK = fact.TeamProjectSK
        inner join dbo.DimPerson Person
        on person.PersonSK = item.System_AssignedTo__PersonSK
        inner join DimIteration Iteration
        on iteration.IterationSK = item.IterationSK
        where fact.RevisionCount is not null AND 
        [Project].[ProjectPath] = '\B2B_CRM\PhProduct'
    ) AS x
    inner join dbo.DimDate [date]
    on x.[[Date]].[Date]]] = [date].[Date]
    WHERE x.RN = 1
    AND Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork IS NOT NULL
    AND Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork = @Something
```